# How to refresh parts of a page in Django + jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, rating

I have created a demo project where I have two links named '1' and '2', and a display of the number 1 or 2 depending on whichever link is clicked.

**models.py**

```
class Count(models.Model):
    num = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^home/$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^count/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.count, name='count'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    c = Count.objects.filter(id=1)
    return render(request, "alpha/home.html", {'c': c})

def count(request, pk):
    c = Count.objects.filter(id=1).update(num=pk)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('alpha:home'))
```

**home.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
{% for c in c %}
    <span id="num"> {{ c.num }} </span>
{% endfor %}

<a href="#" onclick="$.ajax({
            url: '{% url 'alpha:count' 1 %}',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#num').text({{ c.num }});
                }
            })">1</a>
<a href="{% url 'alpha:count' 2 %}">2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see that the `count` view updates the model and then reloads the `home` view, thus refreshing the answer (which is 1 or 2). But in the template file I have tried to include jQuery library and tried to call the first link in such a way that the page doesn't reload. I know very little JS, so this is basically copy/paste code. And clicking the first link doesn't do anything right now. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `count` view should return Count value and not redirect:

```
def count(request, pk):
    c = Count.objects.filter(id=1).update(num=pk)
    return new HttpResponse(pk)
```

Your AJAX call should update `span`'s value based on the response from the server:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '{% url 'alpha:count' 1 %}',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#num').text(data);
    }
})
```

Additionally I'd extract AJAX into a function, eg:

```
function updateCount(value){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/count/' + value,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#num').text(data);
        }
    })
}
```

and then reuse it twice in your HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="updateCount(1);">1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="updateCount(2);">2</a>
```

Comment: I've got a few questions. What is the purpose of `new` and why are we returning the `pk` in the last line of count view. Aren't we supposed to return `c`?

Comment: You cannot return model directly as far as I know (or it's just for JsonResponse, I'm not sure).

In your code you don't need to get a whole object but just its attribute value, that's why it returns `pk` only.

Comment: This doesn't work. I have included your `updateCount` function with `<script></script>` tags in the template, and then used the `updateCount(2)` on the second link. I did the first link like your first example. None of the links work and the value doesn't get updated. I am REALLY new to JS. Do you think I am missing something? If you are not telling me something which is really basic and you assume that I should know that already, please share that. I have copied your code and pasted it exactly as it is.

Comment: Do you get any errors in Django's console while running?

Also, add `console.log(data)` before `$('#num').text(data);` in `success` function and look for the output in your browser's console. Is there anything shown?

Comment: What about JS console in browser after adding `console.log`?

Comment: I am really sorry for this, my jQuery was not getting detected. Thanks for teaching me the console thingy. Now I have a different question. My jQuery file was right beside the template file `home.html` in the same folder. Why was it not getting detected? I am using cdn now, and it works fine!

Comment: You have to include it into the HTML file: `<script src="jquery.js"></script>`